# Conditional custom price suffix for variable products in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, price, product-variations

I have set the price suffix for all my products in Woocommerce (“per box” in my case). This works for variable products as well as for single products without problems.

Now I want this prefix to change to “per pallet” for some product variations of a product. I’ve read a lot and tried a lot, but I haven’t found a solution yet that could be applied to individual variants of a product. Can anyone help me?

Below is the Code I tried. There are no error messages, but it does not change the price of a specific id.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_available_variation', 'variation_price_custom_suffix', 10, 3 );
function variation_price_custom_suffix( $variation_data, $product, $variation ) {
    $args = array(
    'post_parent'   => get_the_ID() // get parent post-ID
);
$variations = get_posts( $args );

foreach ( $variations as $variation ) {

    // get variation ID
    $variation_ID = $variation->ID;

    // get variation price
    $variation_price = $product_variation->get_price_html();

    get_post_meta( $variation_ID , '_text_field_date_expire', true );

}
    if($variation_ID == 732) {
        $variation_data['price_html'] .= "Text after price";
    }
    return $variation_data;
}
```

Many thanks in advance and many greetings
keved

Comment: Show us what you've tried (code, best effort) and how the actual outcome deviates from the expected result, so we can help you on your way.

Comment: I`ve updated my post :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making it much more complicated that it should be and there are some mistakes:

- The parent variable product is the `$product` function argument (variable).
- You don't need to make a foreach loop, as you are already in it.
- You are not using: `get_post_meta( $variation_ID , '_text_field_date_expire', true );`
- `$variation` variable is the array of the current variation data ([see here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Product_Variable.html#300-325))
- `$variation['variation_id']` is the product variation ID
- The parent variable product id(if needed) is `$product->get_id()`

**So 2 posible ways:**

1) Targeting all the product variations of a specific variable product:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_available_variation', 'variation_price_custom_suffix', 10, 3 );
function variation_price_custom_suffix( $variation_data, $product, $variation ) {
    // For a specific variable product ID (and all its variations)
    if( $product->get_id() == 732 ) {

        $date_expire = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_text_field_date_expire', true );

        $variation_data['price_html'] .= ' ' . __("Text after price");
    }

    return $variation_data;
}
```

2) Targeting a unique product variations ID:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_available_variation', 'variation_price_custom_suffix', 10, 3 );
function variation_price_custom_suffix( $variation_data, $product, $variation ) {
    // For a specific product variation ID
    if( $variation['variation_id'] == 732 ) {

        $date_expire = get_post_meta( $variation['variation_id'], '_text_field_date_expire', true );

        $variation_data['price_html'] .= ' ' . __("Text after price");
    }

    return $variation_data;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should better work now, **but you will need to complete it to use your custom field**.

Related: [Adding custom text to the variation price in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52599426/adding-custom-text-to-the-variation-price-in-woocommerce/52599591?r=SearchResults&s=1|34.5891#52599591)

Comment: Wow great thanks for your help, ist worked for me :)

Comment: Another Question to this Problem: How can I also apply this change to the price range display (on the shop homepage and in the detailed view of the product if no variant has yet been selected)?